# How to add a condition inside criteria in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

As an example, I want to have an averageIf and inside one of the criterias, criteria_range: H:H I want inside criteria a condition such as TEXT(H;"mmm") = "Jan" to extract the month. Also tried something else but didn't work either:
'=AVERAGEIF(TEXT(H:H;"[$-409]mmm"); "Jan"; K:K)

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, AVERAGEIF and similar only work with direct criteria as `=,<,>...` and so on. Also, as criteria_range it must be a range of cells, not a function result. Consider using helper columns with the values you want or maybe filtering with SUMPRODUCT and double unary operators. You should add a data example and you expected output.

Comment: Do you have more than one year's data? If not, use the start and end of the month as criteria. If you do, you'll need a helper column or a different approach.

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you could use either `SUMPRODUCT` or `FILTER` functions to apply your criteria.  Then `AVERAGE` the results.